# Stop php running background with fastcgi_finish_request

Tags: php

My code:

```
<?php    
echo 'I see';
fastcgi_finish_request();
sleep(300);
echo 'I dont see';
```

How to stop script after fastcgi_finish_request.
Thanks you !

Comment: Well, the script stops when it stops (exit, return, end of script...)!  fastcgi_finish_request just flushes the response output.  Check out tuxrampage note on the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php), though for a couple of issues using this function.